# SQL pivot to arrange data to 12 months output

Tags: sql, oracle, pivot

I have a Table named: ListOfdates

```
 TYPE  |    O_DATE    |   C_DATE     |
+------+-------------+---------------+
   A     15-JAN-2017       (NULL)
   A     15-JAN-2017       (NULL)
   A     15-JAN-2017     25-APR-2017
   A     15-JAN-2017       (NULL)
   A     24-FEB-2017       (NULL)
   A     15-MAY-2017       (NULL)
   B     15-MAY-2017     25-MAY-2017
   C     15-MAY-2017       (NULL)
   D     15-MAY-2017     26-MAY-2017
   A     15-MAY-2017       (NULL)`
```

I want to arrange it into the below,

```
`MONTH |  Type A   |Total|  Type B   |Total|  Type C   |Total|  Type D   |Total|
       | A_o | A_c | T_o | B_o | B_c | T_o | C_o | C_c | T_o | D_o | D_c | T_o |
JAN    |  4  |  0  |  4  |  0  |  0  |  0  |  0  |  0  |  0  |  0  |  0  |  0  |
FEB    |  1  |  0  |  5  |  0  |  0  |  0  |  0  |  0  |  0  |  0  |  0  |  0  |
MAR    |  0  |  0  |  0  |  0  |  0  |  0  |  0  |  0  |  0  |  0  |  0  |  0  |
APR    |  0  |  1  |  4  |  0  |  0  |  0  |  0  |  0  |  0  |  0  |  0  |  0  |
MAY    |  2  |  0  |  6  |  1  |  0  |  0  |  1  |  0  |  0  |  0  |  1  |  0  |
JUN    |  0  |  0  |  0  |  0  |  0  |  0  |  0  |  0  |  0  |  0  |  0  |  0  |
...`
```

The conditions are,

o_date will add a count to open for the month and type.

If c_date is not null, it will add a count to the close for the month and type

else if it is null for the c_date, there won't be a count to the close.

also, there will be a total count for the number of open for each type accumulated from the start of the year.

All 12 months must be displayed.

The acronym are:

```
`O_DATE = open date
C_DATE = close date
A_o = Type A open
A_c = Type A close
B_o = Type A open
B_c = Type B close
C_o = Type C open
T_o = Total open for the type (example may have 2 type A that is open)

etc...`
```

Is there a way to do it in sql with pivot?

Answer (score 0):

I would do this using conditional aggregation, but first you have to unpivot the data:

```
select to_char(dte, 'MON'),
       sum(case when type = 'A' then open else 0 end) as A_o, 
       sum(case when type = 'A' then close else 0 end) as A_c, 
       sum(case when type = 'A' then 1 else 0 end) as A_total, 
       . . .
from ((select type, o_date as dte, 1 as open, 0 as close from t) union al
      (select type, c_date as dte, 0 as open, 1 as close from t)
     ) oc
group by to_char(dte, 'MON')
order by min(dte);
```

Comment: sorry, i'm quite new to this, may i know what is t, al and oc?

Comment: Those are called table aliases and are an important part of SQL.